# Bulk shifting lines in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I traced sidewalks lines from parcel data provided to me, but now my boss wants the lines shifted closer to the street. Is there a way to do this in bulk, and keep the attributes? I have 1150 lines and I'd rather not have to do each one individually. I know I'll probably need to touch up the corners again, which I am fine with. Some need to be shifted to the left and some to right. I know you can use the Copy Parallel tool, but I can't seem to keep the same attributes.

[image]

Comment: If you have a centerline of sorts could you buffer it wide enough to include the sidewalk lines, split it with those lines and keep only the core buffer, then use a negative buffer on that buffer polygon?